# Showing unbiasedness of the variance estimator: $E(\hat \sigma^2)=\sigma^2$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, random-variables

There is an infinite population characterized by a probability model. A simple random sample of size $n$ is $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$. Moreoever, $X_i$ are i.i.d. according to the model.

The population mean is $\mu = E(X_i)$. The sample mean is $\hat \mu=\frac {1}{n}\sum^n _{i=1}X_i$. $E(\hat \mu)=\mu$.

Variance of the estimator is $V(\hat \mu)=\frac {\sigma^2}{n}$, where ${\sigma^2}=V(X_i)$. Also, $\hat \sigma^2=\frac {1}{n-1}\sum^n_{i=1}(X_i-\hat \mu)^2$.

I want to show that $E(\hat \sigma^2)=\sigma^2$ .

My confusion here is that if $X_i$ is random variable, does this mean the sample mean $\hat \mu$ is also a random variable? I also tried the fact that $\sum^n_{i=1}(X_i-\hat \mu)^2 = \sum^n_{i=1}[(X_i- \mu)+(\mu-\hat \mu)]^2$, but I'm stuck on how to proceed forward.

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://mycourses.aalto.fi/pluginfile.php/364838/mod_resource/content/1/Proof%20that%20Sample%20Variance%20is%20Unbiased.pdf) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1hgiAla3KI)?

Comment: Start with a **big** sheet of paper. Write $\hat \mu = \bar X$ and $E(S^2) = E\{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i(X-\bar X)^2\}.$ Then in the last equation of your Question write out the square of the two terms inside square brackets, argue that the cross-product term is 0, expand the first term to argue that it is $n\sigma^2$, and notice that the last term is $nVar(\bar X) = n\frac{\sigma^2}{n}.$

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding, we have
\begin{equation}
 \hat \sigma^2=\frac {1}{n-1}\sum^n_{i=1}(X_i-\hat \mu)^2
    =\frac {1}{n-1}\sum^n_{i=1} X_i^2 - \frac {2}{n-1}\hat{\mu} \sum^n_{i=1}X_i + \frac {n}{n-1}\hat{\mu}^2
\end{equation}
Taking expectations
\begin{equation}
 E \hat \sigma^2
 =\frac {1}{n-1}\sum^n_{i=1} E X_i^2 - \frac {2}{n-1} E (\hat{\mu} \sum^n_{i=1}X_i) + \frac {n}{n-1}E\hat{\mu}^2
\end{equation}
Notice that
\begin{align}
 E X_i^2 &= \sigma^2 +\mu^2\\
 E (\hat{\mu} \sum^n_{i=1}X_i) &= nE (\hat{\mu} \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1}X_i)=nE \hat{\mu}^2
\end{align}
So
\begin{equation}
 E \hat \sigma^2
 =\frac {n}{n-1}(\sigma^2 + \mu^2)- \frac {2n}{n-1} E \hat{\mu}^2 + \frac {n}{n-1}E\hat{\mu}^2
  =\frac {n}{n-1}(\sigma^2 + \mu^2- E \hat{\mu}^2 ) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Notice that
\begin{equation}
 E \hat{\mu}^2 
 =
 \frac{1}{n^2}
 E (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2
 =
 \frac{1}{n^2}
 \sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{E X_i^2}_{\mu^2 + \sigma^2} + \sum_{i \neq j} \underbrace{E(X_iX_j)}_{=0}
\end{equation}
we get
\begin{equation}
 E \hat{\mu}^2
 =
 \frac{1}{n^2}
 (n (\mu^2 + \sigma^2) + (n^2-n)(\mu^2)) 
 =
 \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2 + \mu^2
\end{equation}
Replacing in $(1)$, we get
\begin{equation}
 E \hat \sigma^2
  =\frac {n}{n-1}(\sigma^2- \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2 )
  =
  \frac{n}{n-1}\frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2 
  =
  \sigma^2
\end{equation}

Comment: You have a mistake here. $E(X_i X_j) = 0$ for $i \neq j$, not $\mu^2$

Comment: you're right - please correct it if you wish @JoseAvilez